# how to find the least number of lists to cover all the elements of the another list with python?

Tags: python, list

I have some lists and one reference list
I need to find the least number lists to cover all the elements of the reference list with python.

For example, if the reference list was:

```
R = [0,3,10,15]
```

and another lists was :

```
li1 = [0,3]
li2 = [0,10]
li3 = [3,10]
li4 = [3,15]
li5 = [10,15]
```

The smallest number of lists needed to cover every element in R is li2 and li4. I want it to give me an output of li2 and li4,
Lists length is not always the same.
Any help?

Comment: `li1` and `li4` could also cover every element in R.Isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasSablik not only 2 elements, it may have more elements or even choose all of them but i want the least number of lists to cover the reference list

Comment: How is this a Python question? In the current state this question is unrelated to Python. Are you able to solve the problem with pen and paper?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA that was just an example my mistake, I edited the question

Comment: Is `li1` and `li2` a solution? Together they contain all elements.

Comment: Would this list contain duplicate numbers?

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes with trial and error we can choose them, but I have no idea how to do that with python code

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm sorry I just used random numbers I replace them with another example

Comment: `li1` and `li5` would also be a solution? This looks like it could be solved using dynamic programming.

Comment: @ThomasSablik no problem if it gives me both of them or the firsts that it can find

Comment: Can `R` contain duplicates? Is it possible that a solution consists of more than 2 lists?

Comment: @ThomasSablik no R  cant contain duplicates and yes it can  consist even all lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming to solve the problem:

```
R = set([0,3,10,15])

lists = [
    [0,3], [0,10], [3,10], [3,15], [10,15]
]

def solution(indexes = None, s = None, index = None):
    if indexes is None:
        indexes = []
    if s is None:
        s = set()
    if index is None:
        index = 0
    if s >= R:
        return indexes
    if index >= len(lists):
        return False
    s1 = solution(indexes + [index], s | set(lists[index]), index + 1)
    s2 = solution(indexes, s, index + 1)
    if not s1 and not s2:
        return False
    if not s1:
        return s2
    if not s2:
        return s1
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return s1
    return s2

print(solution())

# Output:
# [1, 3]
```

That's a first recursive approach. You can improve it using an iterative approach with memoisation.

Comment: Thank you but  sorry I didn't get indexes, s and index

Comment: @Roxana What do you mean? It works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dkse2GY1eRbqEpnE

Comment: in what situation would `s > R` be True? I can't figure out why you chose `s >= R` instead of `s == R`. (not saying it's wrong, just trying to figure it out)

Comment: @PaulH E.g. `R = [1,2,4,5], li1 = [1,2,3], li2 = [4,5]`. It's not clear if the lists are subsets of `R`

Comment: Ahh, I see. Superset vs equivalent set. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The expected outcome in the example of OP is `[li1,li5]` and `[li2,li4]`. Preferably the solution should also capture examples where one list captures all elements or examples where only three lists capture all elements.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

R = [0,3,10,15]
li1 = [0,3]
li2 = [0,10]
li3 = [3,10]
li4 = [3,15]
li5 = [10,15]
```

Make an initial empty DataFrame with columnnames and index with values R.

```
dat = pd.DataFrame(columns=['li1','li2','li3','li4','li5'], index=R)
```

For each list in the DataFrame we are going to indicate if the index exists (which is R). We put every list in the DataFrame using enumerate.

```
for i,j in list(enumerate([li1,li2,li3,li4,li5])):
    dat.iloc[:,i] = dat.index.isin(j)*1
```

To investigate which combination of columns have all elements, we can use Itertools to find all 2 paired combinations and check if all elements are larger than zero.

```
A = list(it.combinations(['li1', 'li2', 'li3', 'li4', 'li5'], 2))

for i in np.arange(0,len(A)):
    ens = dat[list(A[i])].apply(sum, 1)
    if all(i > 0 for i in ens): print('A combination that contains all elements:', list(A[i]))
```

**Outcome:**

```
A combination that contains all elements: ['li1', 'li5'] 
A combination that contains all elements: ['li2', 'li4']
```

To investigate the least number of lists, one can start with one list putting `it.combinations` to 1 and then progressively research combinations of two, three or more lists.

Comment: thank you but what is `it` in this line `A = list(it.combinations(['li1', 'li2', 'li3', 'li4', 'li5'], 2))`  ?

Comment: oops, that slipped through, is itertools: `import itertools as it`

Answer (score 0):

It's brute-force, but I would use `set` objects after putting your lists into a dictionary:

```py
from itertools import combinations

R = set([0, 3, 10, 15])
data = dict(
    li1 = [0, 3],
    li2 = [0, 10],
    li3 = [3, 10],
    li4 = [3, 15],
    li5 = [10, 15],
)

for n in range(2, len(data)):
    for keys in combinations(data.keys(), n):
        subset = [data[key] for key in keys]
        if set([item for sublist in subset for item in sublist]) == R:
            break
        
print(keys)
```

And that prints:
`li1 li5`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sorry it gave me this error :   for key1, key2 in combinations(data.keys(), n):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Roxana sorry about that. copy/paste error. check the edit